# Why is d3 undefined in Chrome console in my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, d3.js

I am importing the d3.js library in my React app like this:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
```

I am creating a basic world map, which is also displayed correctly in the browser. However, when I try to do something like this in Chrome console:

```
d3.select("path")
```

I am getting an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined

I guess it has something to do how React works, and being a novice in React right now I don't know what i am missing here right now. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because webpack (or any other bunder) holds it in module scope. To prevent collisions between modules, bundlers wrap those with functions. You can consider all imports, as local function variables:

```js
function yourModule(require) {
  const d3 = require('d3');

  // you can use d3 here within your module
}

you're not able to use it here, somewhere outside
```

Comment: So I basically cannot use the console for debugging?

Comment: If you really want to, you can store needed stuff in global scope, just add `window.d3 = d3` into your module

Comment: Yeah right. Forgot about the global option. However, from your comment it sounds that this is not an usual approach in development? What do you do when debugging?

Comment: You can use breakpoints or `debugger` keyword in chrome to stop and debug on specific place in your code. You also should enable source maps to see original code, not minimized.